# Error only with adb

Tags: java, android, adb

I am writing a very simple Android app constituted by an activity and a service. I load my service in the activity by doing

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, RemoteIntegerService.class);
    ComponentName name = startService(mServiceIntent);
    TextView mainText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainText);
    mainText.setText(name == null ? "(null)" : name.getClassName());
}
```

When I run the application on my Galaxy Tab or in a virtual device, everything looks fine, and the mainText reads the correct class name.

But when I start the app in Eclipse with adb's "debug over usb feature", I have an error in the Intent constructor (in the real device as well as in a virtual one). Here's the stack trace :

```
RemoteInteger [Android Application] 
DalvikVM[localhost:8621]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Class load: RemoteIntegerService)    
        DexFile.defineClass(String, ClassLoader, int, ProtectionDomain) line: not available [native method] 
        DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(String, ClassLoader) line: 207  
        PathClassLoader.findClass(String) line: 211 
        PathClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 540   
        PathClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 500    
        RemoteIntegerActivity.onResume() line: 28   
        Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Activity) line: 1153   
        RemoteIntegerActivity(Activity).performResume() line: 4428  
        ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(IBinder, boolean) line: 2217   
        ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(IBinder, boolean, boolean) line: 2255   
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1769 
        ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 122   
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1002  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 132 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4025    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 491  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 841  
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 599 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<8> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
    Thread [<7> Binder Thread #1] (Running)
```

**Edit**

- Copied the full stack trace
- MyService -> RemoteIntegerService (real name, to be coherent with stack trace)

**Edit 2 - Sub-question**

I can't find any information about the error. The program just stops, I see the stack trace, but nothing else. On Visual Studio I have a popup describing the Exception that occured. Is there anything like that in Eclipse ?

Comment: This doesn't seem like the full stack trace.  There have to be a few more lines at the top.

Comment: I don't get this: do you use a different method to create the apk (other than eclipse)? If so, how do you build it?

Comment: No, I build the apk with Eclipse, but once I have ran it (with Eclipse), it remains installed on the device so I can run it like any app without Eclipse. When I run from adb in Eclipse, I have the bug, when I run it without Eclipse, it runs fine. (But I'd like to be able to debug with Eclipse...)

Comment: Ok I feel stupid... I had a breakpoint on the service class (I didn't even know that was possible), and the debugger was just reaching the breakpoint. Should I delete the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Julien pointed out the debugger may stop with the message:

```
defineClass(String, ClassLoader, int, ProtectionDomain) line: not available [native method]
```

because a breakpoint has been set on a class. Removing the breakpoint solve this problem.